# Fixing Local Skew in Leptonica 1.68

Tags: ios, iphone, c, image-processing

I'm having an interesting issue with Leptonica that I'm wondering if other SO members have seen.

I'm doing a deskew operation, and having severe artifacting issues, so much so that nobody would rightly accept the results, which degrade the image quality more than they benefit it.

Here's the relevant code that produces the deskew operation:

```
    // Make a black and white version for deskew calculations
    l_int32 thresh;
    PIX * deskewbw = pixMaskedThreshOnBackgroundNorm(pix,NULL,10,15,25,10,2,2,0.1,&thresh);  
    NSLog(@"Used threshold of %d to normalize image for deskew",thresh);

    // Find the local skew
    PTA * ptas, *ptad;
    pixGetLocalSkewTransform(deskewbw, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, &ptas, &ptad);

    // Cleanup the first B/W version
    pixDestroy(&deskewbw);
    
    // Deskew the original image
    PIX * deskewgray = pixProjectivePtaGray(pix, ptad, ptas, 128);

    // Reduce the deskewed original image to B/W
    pixbw = pixMaskedThreshOnBackgroundNorm(deskewgray, NULL, 10, 15, 25, 10, 2, 2, 0.1, &thresh);
```

Whether I use this, or the pixDeskewLocal function (which does something similar) I get some VERY UGLY results with an interlaced line effect:

[image: Ugly deskew artifacts]

Just for comparison, here is the original (slightly skewed) image:

[image: Original Image]

This happens whether the original is a black or white foreground, and is more severe in areas that are shifted more.  I'm tempted at this point just to have iOS do the rendering for me to avoid Leptonica for this particular operation, but that increases the number of conversions in my workflow, which I'd rather avoid if possible.

Has anyone else encountered/overcome this issue before?  Any pointers on why this happens/how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use function `pixEndianByteSwap(pixbw);` to fix this problem.

Comment: Mark, how I wish you were around four months ago to help with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this from an image processing perspective, and realized that I had probably made a mistake in reading data into Leptonica, rather than Leptonica being the culprit here, and as it turns out, I was right.

The pixel spacing for this glitch was 4, and as it turns out, Leptonica reads data in words, processing from MSB/MSb to LSB/LSb, leading to a conflict between the way that CGContext writes data, and how Leptonica reads it.  This isn't as big of a problem if you read the data into Leptonica as rgba, because once you flatten it to greyscale or B/W, the error mostly vanishes (at the cost of some dynamic range) but since I was reading data in as 8-bit grayscale, the error didn't vanish, but instead manifested as you see above.

On Little-Endian systems, the data needs to be divided into words, and the byte order reversed to form a sensible image from a CGContext, on Big-Endian systems, no change is necessary. I'd prefer finding a method of having CGContext do this for me, but for now, I'll fix this the hard way.